# Evitar que excepción detenga mi programa de Python con selenium

Tags: html, python, web, formularios, selenium

Lo que sucede es que estoy utilizando selenium para automatizar el llenado de un formulario web, pero de vez en cuando aparece la excepción **ElementNotInteractableException** la cual capturo en con un try, pero me gustaría que en vez que se detenga el proceso simplemente se saltara al siguiente elemento de llenado. Estoy utilizando el Xpath para encontrar los campos en la pagina web.

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para refrescar el funcionamiento del sitio. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: En general con un Try Catch se realiza lo que pides en Java, en python creo que es https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
ids_inputs = {}  # lista de ids elementos inputs
for id in ids_inputs:
    try:
        elemento_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, id)
        # también puedes hacerlo por By.NAME, By.CLASS_NAME, By.CSS_SELECTOR, By.TAG_NAME, etc
        elemento_input.click()
    except ElementNotInteractableException as e:
        # si se cae, continuará con el siguiente elemento
        pass
```

Recuerda compartir el código que haz utilizado.